# Python: Having trouble getting pygame to work. on PC

Tags: python, pygame

## When I use this from a tutorial.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()


black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
green    = (   0, 255,   0)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)


size=[700,500]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("jons cool game")
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Pygame\Example.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I'm using v3.3.1 and pygame 3.3.

Comment: Did you install Pygame for Python 3 or for Python 2? Are you running this script with Python 3?

Answer (score 3):

According to the `ImportError` you do not have pygame installed with Python 3.3.

On the pygame's website there is no `3.3 version`. I would suggest to use Python 3.2 and download the corresponding pygame version from [pygame.org](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml)

Comment: Well, I downloaded it and when i install it says repair so I assume it is installed. I'll try that.

Comment: I installed 3.2 and pygame 3.2 it now runs but is all laggy.

Comment: That was because there wasn't a pygame.quit() and the program would crash. Perhaps I should just read further before I start asking questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Might be a problem with your pygame installation. Check the documentation and tutorials on the website to make sure you set it up correctly.